# Perl: print the contents of multiple files after reading the file list from a file

Tags: bash, perl

My datafile.txt has the list of filenames:

```
/tmp/dir1/file1
/tmp/dir2/file2
/tmp/dir3/file3
...
/tmp/dir100/file100
```

I want my Perl script to read this datafile.txt file and let it print the content of each file from datafile.txt.

That is, how can I accomplish the following in Perl?

```
for file in `cat datafile.txt`; do
       cat $file
done
```

I tried the following and have difficulty:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $fh, '<', '/tmp/datafile.txt');

foreach my $filename (<$fh>) {
        open(my $fh1, '<', $filename);
        foreach(<$fh1>) {
                chomp;
                print "$_\n";
        }
        close $fh1;
}

close $fh;
```

Comment: You forgot to `chomp $filename`

Comment: You got the answer to solve the problem, to `chomp` the filename to be opened.  But also note -- the `foreach (<$fh>)` reads all lines into a list and then iterates through that.  Once you are reading from a filehandle you want to do it line-by-line (unless there is a _very_ specific reason not to), so use `while (<$fh>)` instead. Btw, to just print out lines you can do `print while <$fh1>;` (but for more processing you mostly do need a loop, of course).

Comment: Why `chomp; print "$_\n"` instead of just `print "$_"`?  That is, why remove the newline and just to add it back in?

Comment: @WilliamPursell: As it stands I agree that it it wasteful. But it can be considered good practice if there is any chance that there may be additional processing between the `chomp` and the `print`. After all, the entire `foreach` can be contracted to `print <$fh1>`. Would you advocate that? It's along the same lines as adding a superfluous comma after the last element of a list, or decoding all input and encoding all output and working only in Unicode characters. Both of those are recognised as being good practice, and I wouldn't fault the unnecessary `chomp` that you picked up. But nor would

Comment: @WilliamPursell: But nor would I correct dropping the `chomp` for a simple `print`. (Note that the double quotes in your `print "$_"` are *very* wrong, and `$_` is the default parameter for `print`.)

Comment: Don't get why many use `foreach` when `for` is a perfectly good synonym.

Comment: ...and instead of `print "$_"` just `print` is even shorter:)

Answer (score 0):

```
  open my $fh_list, '<', '/tmp/datafile.txt' or die;
  while(<$fh_list>){
    chomp;
    open my $fh, '<', $_ or die "Cannot read $_\n";
    print while <$fh>;
    close $fh;
  }
  close $fh_list;
```

...or using `File::Slurp` and given enough memory this could simply be:

```
use File::Slurp;
print read_file($_) for map{chomp;$_} read_file('/tmp/datafile.txt');
```

And of course you could skip perl altogether with this linux command:

```
cat /tmp/datafile.txt | xargs cat
```